# Modifying noise intensity by different SNR

Tags: signal-processing, noise

I was trying out the signal process library `ThinkDSP`.

My desired operation is to add some noise on the original `.wav` file

I've known that this operation is easy to achieve by `add_noise = my_wav + noise`

However, I would like to modify the noise under different SNR conditions

How do I achieve this by ThinkDSP? Or other methods are also welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to calculate the power in your wav file and determine the noise power that will give you the desired snr.  In Python with scipy this is quite easy.

```
# Import scipy
import scipy as sp

# Signal power in data from wav file
psig = sig.var()

# For 10 dB SNR, calculate linear SNR (SNR = 10Log10(Psig/Pnoise)
snr_lin = 10.0**(10.0/10.0)

# Find required noise power
pnoise = psig/snr_lin

# Create noise vector
noise = sp.sqrt(pnoise)*sp.randn(len(sig))

# Add noise to signal
sig_plus_noise = sig + noise
```

See this answer for more information [Add random noise with specific SNR to a signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52913749/add-random-noise-with-specific-snr-to-a-signal/52949439#52949439)